# How to investigate the acute growth of the AJP threads number in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, mod-jk, jvm-crash, ajp

We have configuration that includes Apache and Tomcat servers  connected by mod_jk.  There are several tomcat servers and request are distributed by the Round-Robin algorithm.  Just recently the number of AJP threads suddenly started growing and the tomcat servers crashed.

We do not see anything unusual in the logs, and the load was below average. The Garbage collection started about 5 minutes before the sudden increase as shown by  New Relic software.

What is the best approach in dealing with this crash?  I am thinking about simulating the load with JMeter, what can be other ideas?

Comment: is it external facing, i.e. open to the world, or in-house only?

Comment: It is open to the world, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an attack? 
Did you have a look at connection logs to detect some unusual activity ?

I would first try to determine if the crash was caused by some external traffic, or by a software issue (some loop): server's network statistics, apache logs.

I would also look at:

- application logs
- resources (CPU, mem, ...),

since the crash may be caused by some kind of bottleneck

Comment: What particular should I pay attention in the connection log?

Comment: Crash was repeated but I do not see anything unusual in the connection log. Should I pay attention only to POST request or GET requests can be dangerous too?